# Odoo 8 with centos 6.5 is not starting

Tags: centos, odoo, odoo-8

I got installed Odoo 8 with my centos 6.5
i use structure at this link:

https://odootricks.wordpress.com/2014/09/30/installing-odoo-8-on-centos-6-with-virtual-python-install/

when i finished the installation i got
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
and the log contains:

```
File "/opt/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 560, in borrow
result = psycopg2.connect(dsn=dsn, connection_factory=PsycoConnection)
File "/home/odoo/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

2016-08-06 10:57:43,817 2637 ERROR ? openerp.addons.bus.bus: Bus.loop    error, sleep and retry
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/odoo/addons/bus/bus.py", line 136, in run
self.loop()
File "/opt/odoo/addons/bus/bus.py", line 114, in loop
with openerp.sql_db.db_connect('postgres').cursor() as cr:
File "/opt/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 609, in cursor
return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
File "/opt/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 181, in __init__
self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
File "/opt/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 498, in _locked
return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 560, in borrow
result = psycopg2.connect(dsn=dsn, connection_factory=PsycoConnection)
File "/home/odoo/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

2016-08-06 10:58:33,833 2637 ERROR ? openerp.sql_db: Connection to the database failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 560, in borrow
result = psycopg2.connect(dsn=dsn, connection_factory=PsycoConnection)
File "/home/odoo/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

2016-08-06 10:58:33,834 2637 ERROR ? openerp.addons.bus.bus: Bus.loop error, sleep and retry
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/odoo/addons/bus/bus.py", line 136, in run
self.loop()
File "/opt/odoo/addons/bus/bus.py", line 114, in loop
with openerp.sql_db.db_connect('postgres').cursor() as cr:
File "/opt/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 609, in cursor
return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
File "/opt/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 181, in __init__
self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
File "/opt/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 498, in _locked
return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 560, in borrow
result = psycopg2.connect(dsn=dsn, connection_factory=PsycoConnection)
File "/home/odoo/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't put postgresql password and odoo admin password in `/etc/odoo-server.conf`